# ValueError : empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

For a current project, I am running a script to count the number of words within a Pandas DataFrame with SciKit-Learn. The script is running well when iterating over several DataFrame columns at once (in this case `txt_main`, `txt_pro`, `txt_con` and `txt_adviceMgmt`).

When selecting only one of the columns instead of all four, e.g. through line `corpus = row['txt_pro']`, I am however receiving the notification `ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words`. This is regardless whether I e.g. selecting `txt_pro` or `txt_con`.

Where is the thought error that lets the script run when all four columns are selected in the given line (`corpus = row[ ]`) but yields an error notification if only one column is selected?

The script looks as follows:

```
# Word frequency analysis
def get_top_n_bigram(row):
    corpus = row['txt_pro']
    n = 10000000
    vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2), stop_words='english').fit(corpus)
    bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus)
    sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0)
    words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
    words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return sum([freq for word, freq in words_freq])

newdf = df.groupby(['stock_symbol', 'quarter']).apply(get_top_n_bigram).to_frame(name = 'frequencies')
newdf.to_excel('total_bigrams_pro.xlsx')
```

And the correponding JSON file which is basis for the DataFrame has the following structure:

```
[
{"gld_index": "1-0", "stock_symbol": "AMG", "gld_id": "7172", "date": "2013-01-01", "author_job_title": "Current Employee - Vice President", "author_location": "Prides Crossing, MA", "txt_main": "I have been working at Affiliated Managers Group full-time (More than 5 years)", "txt_pro": "AMG has built and continues to develop its position as a world-class asset management company. Working in this entrepreneurial culture enables smart, driven and focused individuals the opportunity to further the company’s mission to be a global leader in the asset management industry. If you are looking for an intellectually challenging workplace there are few competitive firms within the financial services industry that offer a comparable range of professional opportunities. As AMG grows and expands its footprint, there will continue to be new and exciting positions within the business for employees to advance their careers.", "txt_con": "Given the “campus” is located north of Boston, meeting up for drinks with friends and associates after work can be challenging.", "txt_adviceMgmt": null, "rating_recommend": 2, "rating_outlook": 2, "rating_ceo": 2, "scr_avg": 5.0, "scr_balance": 5.0, "scr_values": 5.0, "scr_opportunities": 5.0, "scr_benefits": 5.0, "scr_management": 5.0},
{"gld_index": "1-1", "stock_symbol": "AMG", "gld_id": "7172", "date": "2014-03-13", "author_job_title": "Former Contractor - Anonymous Contractor", "author_location": "Beverly, MA", "txt_main": "I worked at Affiliated Managers Group as a contractor (Less than a year)", "txt_pro": "No reason whatsoever to work at AMG as a temp from an employment agency especially if you are the only one from your agency - You will be depressed or go insane! They are temp/contractor unfriendly.\n\nIf you are from an audit firm, you probably don't have much choice but to go and represent your audit firm. In your case, the fact that you will most likely come as a group from your audit firm may help you maintain your sanity.\n\nThe good thing about being a part of an audit group @ AMG is that they will assign a room to your group with a large camera close-by to watch and listen to your conversations.\n\nAnother good thing is that they will provide a phone room (probably bugged with an eavesdropping device) to secretly record your personal conversations.\n\nFinally, IT just got smart by adding the word 'contractor' to the e-mail addresses of contractors or temps! This way, they are alerting everyone to filter you out from the several, daily secret e-mails!!", "txt_con": "Your employment agency will most likely paint the most beautiful picture of this gated 'castle' located somewhere in \"wealth land\" 600 Some Street in Beverly, whereby chefs cook magnificent free lunch for the employees, cozy gym in a mansion etc.....well, they probably don't know you are not allowed in the gym, you are not part of this free lunch program which is meant for the privileged full-time AMG staff. They will also forget to tell you about this secret culture @ AMG!!! Is it a cult?\n\nYou are confined to your desk or room (in case of a audit group). You are allowed to go to the bathroom assigned to your group, you can use the photocopy machine (Camera? Where?). If you are the type that likes to stretch your legs after sitting for long hours, be careful where you go and how often!! HR will probably just appear like a fairy in front of you from nowhere and ask if they can walk you around (knowing fully well that you have worked there for months and you know your way around your confinement!)\n\nWhat is all this secrecy about? It seems to be more than just protecting vital information (which is normal for any company and understandable considering the nature of their business). Is there more to it?", "txt_adviceMgmt": "Use some of your charitable contributions to provide food for contractors/ temps. You can begin charity from home! Food is way too cheap in America!!!....especially the type of nature-abundant leaves and flowers you serve for lunch.\n\nAlso, keep everyone healthy irrespective of employment status- Open the gym for contractors too!! They will work more efficiently (great ROI). Remember to put posters all over the gym to read \" shhhhh\". This way full-time employees will remember not to discuss those secrets!!!\n\nGive some incentives to those front desk girls....they'll stay longer!", "rating_recommend": 0, "rating_outlook": 1, "rating_ceo": 1, "scr_avg": 1.0, "scr_balance": 1.0, "scr_values": 1.0, "scr_opportunities": 1.0, "scr_benefits": 1.0, "scr_management": 1.0},
{"gld_index": "1-2", "stock_symbol": "AMG", "gld_id": "7172", "date": "2011-09-15", "author_job_title": "Former Employee - Anonymous Employee", "author_location": "Beverly, MA", "txt_main": "Smart, driven, risk-oriented people; intellectually challenging environment; innovator in its industry so there is always something new going on; long hours and stressful at times but very respectful of personal commitments- they strike the right balance; compensation is very good, benefits are phenomenal, and expectations about both are very clear; IT and HR departments are the best I've ever worked with.", "txt_pro": "Smart, driven, risk-oriented people; intellectually challenging environment; innovator in its industry so there is always something new going on; long hours and stressful at times but very respectful of personal commitments- they strike the right balance; compensation is very good, benefits are phenomenal, and expectations about both are very clear; IT and HR departments are the best I've ever worked with.", "txt_con": "The only downside to AMG is that because it is so successful, people don't leave very often, so there is very little upward mobility. It is also a relatively lean organization so there aren't many management levels (a good thing mostly). Thus, if you are a subject expert and are happy with a role that allows you to flourish in your subject area, then this is a great place to be. Similarly, if you want a job that you can leverage into a better opportunity down the road, this is a great stepping stone. However, if you are looking for a place to join and move around or \"climb the ladder,\" you will be frustrated.", "txt_adviceMgmt": null, "rating_recommend": 2, "rating_outlook": null, "rating_ceo": 2, "scr_avg": 4.0, "scr_balance": 5.0, "scr_values": null, "scr_opportunities": 4.0, "scr_benefits": 5.0, "scr_management": 4.5},
{"gld_index": "1-0", "stock_symbol": "MMM", "gld_id": "446", "date": "2017-05-14", "author_job_title": "Current Employee - Technical Aide", "author_location": "Maplewood, MN", "txt_main": "I have been working at 3M part-time (More than 3 years)", "txt_pro": "Respectful treatment, flexible hours, trainings and events, networking", "txt_con": "Not easy to move up, very competitive hiring process (150+ candidates for FT jobs)", "txt_adviceMgmt": null, "rating_recommend": 2, "rating_outlook": 1, "rating_ceo": 2, "scr_avg": 4.0, "scr_balance": 4.0, "scr_values": 5.0, "scr_opportunities": 3.0, "scr_benefits": 3.0, "scr_management": 4.0}
]
```

The full error message is shown here:
[image]

Comment: I feel like your're facing the [x,y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Your main goal is to _count the number of words within a Pandas DataFrame_ , right? Within one column or all columns?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Correct - I am planning to count the number of words within the DataFrame, but separated by Column. When iterating over all columns it works, it's just yielding the error when picking only one column.

Comment: I tested it on a sample pandas series (selecting one column from a dataframe) works fine. _Perhaps your documents only contain stop words?_ Can you take a look at your data.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts. I have checked for the stop words point but the document contains full texts with meaningful words (stop words are words like I, the, he etc). Let me know how would like me to send you the data please.

Comment: I know about stop words, you can use paste bin and comment the link here? Just a small sample of dataframe you're using.

Comment: Ok could have known that you are aware of stop words. Please find enclosed the link to the sample: https://pastebin.com/E6epBqCC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218166/discussion-between-nauman-naeem-and-m-s).

Answer (score 1):

This is the output of my experiment.
(Answering as can't post a pic in comment.)
[image]

Comment: Ok that's weird. I have by the way added the full error message I am receiving as appendix to the original question text. It is apparently triggered by line `  newdf = df.groupby(['stock_symbol', 'quarter']).apply(get_top_n_bigram).to_frame(name = 'frequencies')`